# Number of solution of three equation in term of $x,y,z,\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the number of all possible values of $\theta$, where $0<\theta<\pi$, for which the system of equations

$\left( {y + z} \right)\cos 3\theta  = xyz\sin 3\theta $

$x\sin 3\theta  = \frac{{2\cos 3\theta }}{y} + \frac{{2\sin 3\theta }}{z}$

$xyz\sin 3\theta  = \left( {y + 2z} \right)\cos 3\theta  + y\sin 3\theta $
have a solution $x_0,y_0,z_0$ with $y_0z_0\ne 0$ .

My approach is as follow

$\left( {y + z} \right)\cos 3\theta  = xyz\sin 3\theta  \Rightarrow \frac{{y + z}}{{xyz}} = \tan 3\theta $

$x\sin 3\theta  = \frac{{2\cos 3\theta }}{y} + \frac{{2\sin 3\theta }}{z} \Rightarrow \sin 3\theta \left( {x - \frac{2}{z}} \right) = \frac{{2\cos 3\theta }}{y} \Rightarrow \tan 3\theta  = \frac{2}{{y\left( {x - \frac{2}{z}} \right)}} = \frac{{2z}}{{y\left( {xz - 2} \right)}} = \frac{{2z}}{{\left( {xyz - 2y} \right)}}$

$xyz\sin 3\theta  = \left( {y + 2z} \right)\cos 3\theta  + y\sin 3\theta  \Rightarrow \sin 3\theta \left( {xyz - y} \right) = \cos 3\theta \left( {y + 2z} \right) \Rightarrow \tan 3\theta  = \frac{{y + 2z}}{{\left( {xyz - y} \right)}}$

$\tan 3\theta  = \frac{{y + z}}{{xyz}} = \frac{{y + 2z}}{{\left( {xyz - y} \right)}} = \frac{{2z}}{{\left( {xyz - 2y} \right)}}$

$xyz = t \Rightarrow \tan 3\theta  = \frac{{y + z}}{t} = \frac{{y + 2z}}{{t - y}} = \frac{{2z}}{{t - 2y}}$.

How do we proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
x y z \sin (3 t)=y \cos (3 t)+z \cos (3 t)&(1)\\
x y z \sin (3 t)=2 y \sin (3 t)+2 z \cos (3 t)&(2)\\
x y z \sin (3 t)=y \sin (3 t)+y \cos (3 t)+2 z \cos (3 t)&(3)\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
y \cos (3 t)+z \cos (3 t)=2 y \sin (3 t)+2 z \cos (3 t)&(1)=(2)\\
y \cos (3 t)+z \cos (3 t)=y \sin (3 t)+y \cos (3 t)+2 z \cos (3 t)&(1)=(3)\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
z \cos (3 t)=y \cos (3 t)-2 y \sin (3 t)\\
z \cos (3 t)=-y\sin(3t)\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$y \cos (3 t)-2 y \sin (3 t)=-y\sin(3t)$$
$$\sin(3t)=\cos(3t)\to \tan(3t)=1$$
$$3t=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\to t=\frac{\pi}{12}+k\frac{\pi}{3}$$
Three solutions in $[0,\pi]$
$$t_1=\frac{\pi}{12};\;t_2=\frac{5\pi}{12};\;t_3=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

$3\theta=t$

By first and third condition $$z\cos t+y\sin t=0$$ By mutiplying $yz$ second condition $$xyz \sin t=2z\cos t+2y\sin t=0$$ Hence  either $x=0$ or $\sin t=\sin 3\theta=0$

It remains to check which values of $\theta$ for which $x=0$ and whether $\sin 3\theta=0$ satisfies the 3 conditions and how many solutions it has .